Customize Spyder layout of panes
I found a lot online about customizing the layout of Spyder panes, including this.  However, they all have to do with shifting pane boundaries or undocking.  I don't want undocked panes and neither do I just want to shift pane boundaries.  Here is what I want to change:
  CURRENT LAYOUT
+-----------------------------------------+
|             |                           |
|             |     Help                  |
|             |     Variable explorer     |
|  Code       |                           |
|  editor     |---------------------------+
|             |                           |
|             |        CONSOLE            |
|             |                           |
+-----------------------------------------+

  DESIRED LAYOUT
+-----------------------------------------+
|             |                           |
|  Code       |     Help                  |
|  editor     |     Variable explorer     |
|             |                           |
|-----------------------------------------|
|                                         |
|                 CONSOLE                 |
|                                         |
+-----------------------------------------+

How can I define the "DESIRED LAYOUT" and switch bacn and forth?
Furthermore, is there any way to squeeze the code editor pane width down to just a handful of columns?  I find that dragging the pane boundary only gets it down to about 50 columns.
Context: Outside of debugging, I don't even use the code editor.  From a lifetime of usage, I am highly reliant on Vim and Bash for all things text.  The only reason I keep the Code editor open is because changes to source code from outside the Spyder editor (e.g., using Vim) are not detected unless I actually click in the code editor pane.  I would like to mostly use the "DESIRED LAYOUT", but switch back to "CURRENT LAYOUT" for debugging.

I can't believe it took months of not years to discover the answer, which should have been obvious.
Each pane as a hamburger icon at the upper right corner, allowing access to a pulldown menu.  One menu item is to unlock the pane.  One can then drag the pane around.  It doesn't behave identically to Windows 10's snapping, but similar.
I didn't manage to get the Editor pane to the upper left corner in my 1st few tries, but eventually manage to do it.  Exactly where to drag it to get corner snapping is something I'm still feeling out.  But it works, eventually.
Of course, one can lock the pane after snapping it to the desired corner.
